# Get form input from one perl document in other

Tags: html, forms, perl, input, cgi

I have the following two perl documents:

1. mailcheck.pl
2. loggingpage.pl

In mailcheck.pl the user enters something in a form that I would like to use in loggingpage.pl. This is how I have linked loggingpage.pl in mailcheck.pl:

```
 (...)
 if (emailoutline.test(x))
 {
  open("./loggingpage.pl");
 } 
 (...)
```

In loggingpage.pl I now want to tie the user input to the variable `my $emailinput`. I have not clue to how to that - I have tried things like `my $emailinput = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};` or `read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});` but obviously the script does not know where the input comes from since it is entered in mailcheck.pl and not loggingpage.pl. I would appreciate any help to solve this "interaction problem" between the two perl documents..

PS:
1. The two documents work fine apart from the interaction with the user input.
2. I already asked a question concerning a test of the user input from the two documents, so if you want to see the whole code please visit: [Get input from HTML form in other document using perl and checking input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747481/get-input-from-html-form-in-other-document-using-perl-and-checking-input)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Storable](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable) to store data in first script and retrieve it from other.

`mailcheck.pl`

```
  @array = ("some", "data");
  store (\@array, "/home/chankey/loggingpage.$$") or die "could not store";
  system("perl", "loggingpage.pl", $$) == 0 or die "error";
```

`loggingpage.pl`

```
my $parentpid = shift;
my $ref = retrieve("/home/chankey/loggingpage.$parentpid") or die "couldn't retrieve";
print Dumper $ref;
```

You've received the `@array` in `$ref`. Now use it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing: `open("./loggingpage.pl");`

You can do something like: `system("/usr/bin/perl  ./loggingpage.pl $emailinput");`

That is assuming that perl is installed at "/usr/bin/perl".